# How does post_save take the data after saving?

Tags: django, signals

django signal post_save
I am curious.

I asked chatgpt.
I read a bit of the docs.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def post_save_comment(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pk ..
```

I can get pk.

characteeeeeersssssssssssss

Comment: `post_save` is activated each time a model instance is saved. What do you mean by: `How does it take the data after saving it`? It should take the data and save or update it to the database...

Comment: I mean how  django get the data (instance argument) after saving?
I am curious about the internal processing.

Answer (score 0):

The signal is emitted in the model's `save_base` method: [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ad41f1c53aa9f2c938df32e4386d8a80138923fc/django/db/models/base.py#L915)

```py
    def save_base(
        self,
        raw=False,
        force_insert=False,
        force_update=False,
        using=None,
        update_fields=None,
    ):
        ... # other stuff

        # Signal that the save is complete
        if not meta.auto_created:
            post_save.send(
                sender=origin,
                instance=self,  # this is how you get the instance argument in your receiver
                created=(not updated),
                update_fields=update_fields,
                raw=raw,
                using=using,
            )
```

More about signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/

Comment: Isn't self the data before saving?

Comment: `self` is the model instance.

Comment: after save? is self  saved?
in the end. how does django get saved data?

Comment: I think that to get the data after saving, we have to lock the table and get the LATEST data

this is wrong?.

and if true i want to avoid table lock.

Comment: The model instance's save method emits the signal and passes the instance, like it was when it was saved, as argument `instance` to the receivers. There is no querying or locking going on unless you call `instance.refresh_from_db()` in the receiver.

Comment: I found out that returning.yesterday. I think django using returning.
And I think returning will return the correct value.

Comment: I found out 
`comment.save()` `comment.id`      
We can get id after saving. even when don't using post_save. id added comment instance

Comment: I will trust django will return the correct value